# Error from SAML TechnicalProfile when executed within SubJourney "80131515: ValidateAsync is not supported for Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider"

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I am setting up a SAML IDP in Azure AD B2C following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy). It works fine when I execute it as an OrchestrationStep in a UserJourney but when I execute it as part of a SubJourney I get the following exception:

```
[
  {
    "Kind": "Headers",
    "Content": {
      "UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint": "urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights",
      "CorrelationId": "<removed>",
      "EventInstance": "Event:ClaimsExchange",
      "TenantId": "<removed>",
      "PolicyId": "<removed>"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Transition",
    "Content": {
      "EventName": "ClaimsExchange",
      "StateName": "Initial"
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Predicate",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.ClaimsExchangeMessageValidationHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "FatalException",
    "Content": {
      "Time": "4:03 PM",
      "Exception": {
        "Kind": "Handled",
        "HResult": "80131515",
        "Message": "ValidateAsync is not supported for Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider",
        "Data": {}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

### The OrchestrationStep that works

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="MySamlExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="my-saml-idp-SAML2" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

### The OrchestrationStep that produces the error

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="InvokeSubJourney" >
  <JourneyList>
    <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="SamlFederationJourney" />
  </JourneyList>
</OrchestrationStep>

...

<SubJourneys>
  <SubJourney Id="SamlFederationJourney" Type="Call">
    <OrchestrationSteps>
      <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="MySamlExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="my-saml-idp-SAML2" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
      </OrchestrationStep>
    </OrchestrationSteps>
  </SubJourney>
</SubJourneys>
```